# Managing SharePoint Online time zones for global organizations

Tags: sharepoint-online, timezone

I have a scenario where I'm setting up a SharePoint Online tenant for an organization that has offices in 6 different timezones.

After consulting this article, https://sharepointmaven.com/sharepoint-time-zone/, it is clear to me that the most practical solution to ensure that timestamps on document libraries make sense is to:

- Leave the Regional time zone settings to default UTC -8 Pacific Time (PT)
- Set the Personal time zone settings for each user based on their home office time zone. Then educate users on changing their personal timezone settings when they are on the road travelling.

Does this sound like a reasonable approach?

I'm mainly concerned in document management scenarios, e.g. how "Date Created" and "Date Modified" are recored in relation to document libraries utilized via the Web UI and Windows Explorer (via the OneDrive Sync client).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your settings are reasonable. After you changed time zone in regional settings, the time in date created will automatically changed to corresponding time at that time zone. SharePoint will handle this part.

Before and after I change the time zone settings. 
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks however it all seems very manual. It would be good if each time you logged into SharePoint or opened a document from the OneDrive sync client that it auto-adjusts the time zone based on where you are. If you have 5/6 offices across the globe who gets to decide what the base time zone is? furthermore, what happens if you are in transit working from an airport?

Comment: @Ushka Per my knowledge, end users will can change the time zone in Delve by hand. The administrators can set the time zone for each site according to the requirement.  You can post your idea in SharePoint UserVoice so MS will know what you want.